# How to represent a value that's not null except for one row?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, constraints

I'm attempting to model the entities for a resume and in doing so I came to the following issue: **all except the most recently held positions have an end date**.

Is there a good way to constrain at most one row allowed to be null.  Event better would be that the single allowed null also had the latest start date.

Another way of saying this is can you specify a constraint that says "not null unless"?

Note: this is a learning exercise I'm doing (as opposed to working on production code).
Here's the scripted table I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employers](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [StartMonth] [int] NULL,
    [StartYear] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EndMonth] [int] NULL,
    [EndYear] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Label] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Resume_Id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [UserProfile_UserId] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employers]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Resume_Employers] FOREIGN KEY([Resume_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Resumes] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Resume_Employers]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employers]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [UserProfile_Employers] FOREIGN KEY([UserProfile_UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [UserProfile_Employers]
GO
```

Comment: What if the person is currently working for two employers?

Comment: that's a good point, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a date which is certain to be an invalid one, like 31.12.9999 instead of `NULL` and then check it on the app side. Otherwise you can set a boolean field to show if a person has quit the position described.

I don't think there is much sense in keeping a single `NULL` value. If you really need it, then create a procedure to check this and call it before each insert or update operation.

P.S. you didnt't consider the case when a person has no job at the time, so all positions will have an end date.
P.P.S. why do you keep month and year as two different `int` fields? just use a `date`.